# Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (normal) while freeing dynamically allocated 2D array of struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, free, calloc

Basically, I am creating 2D array of struct using calloc(). Then I utilize that array and I free that allocated space, while freeing it I am getting "double free or corruption (!prev)". Code is written in C language.

---

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>

typedef struct  complex_num{
    double real;
    double imag;
}comp;

void transpose(comp *arr, int height, int width);
void change(comp *arr, int width);

void main(){    
        int width = 64, height = 64;

        int len = width;
        comp *fft[len];
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
                fft[i] = (comp *)calloc(len, sizeof(comp));
        }


        for (int scan=0;scan<height;scan++){
                for (int pix=0;pix<width;pix++){
                        fft[scan][pix].real = 1.0;
                        fft[scan][pix].imag = 0.0;
                }
                change(&fft[scan][0], len);
        }
        transpose(&fft[0][0], len, len);
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                change(&fft[i][0], len);
        }
        transpose(&fft[0][0], len, len); 
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                free(fft[i]);
        }
}
void transpose(comp *arr, int height, int width){
        comp var;
        for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<width;j++){
                        if(j>i){
                                var = *((arr + (i*width)) + j);
                                *((arr + i*width) + j) = *((arr + j*width) + i);
                                *((arr + j*width) + i) = var;
                        }
                }
        }
}

void change(comp *arr, int width){
        for(int i=0; i<width; i++){
                (arr + i)->real = 5.0;
                (arr + i)->imag = 6.9;
        }
}
```

---

Error message:

```
    *** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000002095010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f05108a77e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f05108b037a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f05108b453c]
./a.out[0x400880]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f0510850830]
./a.out[0x400509]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 467935                     /path/to/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 00:00 467935                     /path/to/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 00:00 467935                     /path/to/a.out
02095000-020b6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7f050c000000-7f050c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f050c021000-7f0510000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f0510610000-7f0510626000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 360788             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f0510626000-7f0510825000 ---p 00000016 00:00 360788             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f0510825000-7f0510826000 rw-p 00015000 00:00 360788             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f0510830000-7f05109f0000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 360750             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f05109f0000-7f05109f9000 ---p 001c0000 00:00 360750             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f05109f9000-7f0510bf0000 ---p 000001c9 00:00 360750             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f0510bf0000-7f0510bf4000 r--p 001c0000 00:00 360750             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f0510bf4000-7f0510bf6000 rw-p 001c4000 00:00 360750             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f0510bf6000-7f0510bfa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f0510c00000-7f0510c25000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 360690             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f0510c25000-7f0510c26000 r-xp 00025000 00:00 360690             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f0510e25000-7f0510e26000 r--p 00025000 00:00 360690             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f0510e26000-7f0510e27000 rw-p 00026000 00:00 360690             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f0510e27000-7f0510e28000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f0510e30000-7f0510e31000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f0510e40000-7f0510e41000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f0510e50000-7f0510e51000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f0510e60000-7f0510e61000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fffc47c7000-7fffc4fc7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                  [stack]
7fffc5242000-7fffc5243000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vdso]
```

### Aborted (core dumped)

I am compiling my code with GCC version 5.4.0. I don't understand the error message and don't know how to debug it. What should I do to free the array of pointers?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Maybe `len` is changed in the code you don't show. Or there is another bug in the code you don't show.

Comment: The posted code does **not** give this error. However, the real code in "// Using fft for doing some operations" is doing something bad that causes this error. If you want to check just remove **all** code between the calloc and the free. You'll see that the error is gone...

Comment: BTW: `exit(1);` Why? That's normally done in case of severe errors

Comment: Here you go - no errors: https://ideone.com/DkhOEc

Comment: you have to paste the structure comp

Comment: @alinsoar doesn't matter what the struct is... it's the code between calloc and free that matters. That code probably change one of the pointers and consequently free will fail

Comment: The origin of your problem is clearly in the "Using fft for doing some operations" part. First thing you can do: check if `len` changes between the two two for loops. You may have a buffer overflow, or a similar problem.

Comment: this thread should be closed. It is not evident how to reproduce it

Comment: I have edited the question, which shows the structure comp and also other code. And I am not changing the value of "len" anywhere in between. Thanks for your responses! @alinsonar and others. Sorry for before I am newbie in asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @hp2304 in case you included the header file `stdlib.h` then you have to provide more informations, otherwise this thread is off-topic.

Comment: I have edited the code structure part in the question @alinsoar. Do I still need to provide the function definitions?

Comment: @hp2304 yes, copy paste here everything that can be compiled and executed for us to reproduce it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Updated question. Now you can execute code given in the question and generate the error.

Comment: `<malloc.h>` is a non-standard header. `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: `comp *fft[len];` is a variable-length array, available since C99. However, C99 also introduced native support for complex numbers. Why are you defining your own?

Comment: Don't cast `calloc()`. It does no good and can hide errors (like a missing `#include <stdlib.h>` (which is not the case here)).

Comment: `(arr + i)->real` is more conventionally written as `arr[i].real`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transpose` blatantly accesses elements outside of the array bounds.

`fft` in `main` is an array of pointers. Each pointer is initialized to point to a block of dynamically allocated memory (via `calloc`).

It looks like this in memory:

```
                                   0            1                  63
fft:  0 [ 0x0000a000 ] ----> [ real; imag | real; imag | ... | real; imag ]
      1 [ 0x0000ff08 ] ----> [ real; imag | real; imag | ... | real; imag ]
      .
      .
      .
     63 [ 0x0001041c ] ----> [ real; imag | real; imag | ... | real; imag ]
```

`fft` has 64 elements, each of which is a pointer. In this example, `fft[0]` has the value `0x0000a000`, at which address there is another 64-element array (created by `calloc`), which stores values of type `comp` (which is a 2-element struct).

Thus `*fft[0]` is the first `comp` struct (at address `0x0000a000`), `*fft[1]` is the second `comp` struct (at address `0x0000a010`), `*fft[2]` is the third `comp` struct (at address `0x0000a020`), etc. Each `comp` struct takes 16 bytes, so the addresses increase by 16 (0x10). The last element of `fft[0]`, `fft[0][63]` lives at address `0x0000a3f0`.

`fft[1]` is the second pointer, pointing to a second (unrelated) block of memory (also created by `calloc`). In this example the instances of `comp` live at addresses `0x0000ff08`, `0x0000ff18`, `0x0000ff28`, etc.

The same thing happens for all elements of `fft`, up to `fft[63]`. In this example the `comp` instances `fft[63][0]`, `fft[63][1]`, `fft[63][2]`, etc. live at addresses `0x0001041c`, `0x0001042c`, `0x0001043c`, etc.

Now consider what `transpose` does. It is called like this:

```
transpose(&fft[0][0], len, len);
```

It accesses memory like this:

```
*((arr + (i*width)) + j)
```

Here `arr` is the first parameter; its value is `&fft[0][0]`, which is the same as `fft[0]`, which in our example is `0x0000a000`.

`width` is 64. `i` and `j` are somewhere between 0 and 63, depending on which loop iteration we're in. Let's assume they're at 63.

Then `i*width` is `63*64` is `4032`, and `arr + 4032` is a pointer to the 4033rd element of the array. But wait! There is no such element; `arr` only has 64 elements.

We're now at memory address `0x00019c00`, which is far outside the bounds of `fft[0]` (recall that its elements only go up to address `0x000a3f0`).

But we're not done yet: To this pointer we add `j` (63), giving `0x00019ff0`. And this pointer is what we dereference with `*`.

Had we written this operation using array notation, it would have looked like

```
arr[i*width + j]
```

which more obviously shows that we're accessing element 4095 of a 64-element array.

`transpose` even writes to this address:

```
*((arr + i*width) + j) = ...
```

This modifies memory that your program doesn't own, thus corrupting the internal data structures used by `malloc` / `calloc` / `free`. That's what the error message `double free or corruption` means: Your code has corrupted data that was needed for `free`, which can happen by freeing the same pointer twice ("double free") or just writing to memory past the end of your arrays (as in your code).

---

To fix your code, change `transpose` to

```
void transpose(comp **arr, int height, int width) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < width; j++) {
            if (j > i) {
                comp var = arr[i][j];
                arr[i][j] = arr[j][i];
                arr[j][i] = var;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and call it as

```
transpose(fft, len, len);
```

This way you don't just pass the address of the first sub-array, but the address of the intermediate pointer array (which in turn lets you access any of the 64 sub-arrays).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and solution.